# Структура сайта

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Создаю сайт, сервис - которым могут пользоваться компании.

**Пролог**: Основной сайт предположу `xxx.ru` | На него раходят пользователи, регистрируются просматривают свой личный кабинет, и имеют возможность создать свою (условную) **компанию**, после чего пользователь может выбрать один из пресетов (дополнений). И активировать его за плату.
Пресет (дополнение), это как отдельный сайт, сервис.
Этим пресетом пользуется некая компания, администратор которой пользователь основного сайта. 
Основной сайт - `xxx.ru` , созданная компания с установленным пресетом `nameCompany.xxx.ru`

**Уточнение** : каждая компания должна иметь ***СВОЮ*** базу данных, я использую mysql.
Адрес должен быть такого типа `nameCompany.xxx.ru`
У каждой компании могут быть сотрудники, которые должны заходить на прямую на свой сервис, например `nameCompany.xxx.ru` и уже вводить логин и пас и попадать на сайт. Основной сайт служит только на администраторов этих компаний.

**Вопрос**:  Создавать ли мне под домены под каждую компанию с ее именем? Пихать туда отдельный сайт, на yii2 сам сервис? И так на каждый под домен? А если я захочу обновления сайта? обновлять на всех под доменах?

**Может есть какой другой выход?**

Может как то генерировать посредством htaccess адрес типа. `nameCompany.xxx.ru` если высчитать у юзера к какой компании он относится. В этом случае как быть с базами данных, рано или поздно их станет за 10000+

Comment: В общем, кому не сложно.. помогите разобраться в столь не легкой структуре

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю решение такое:
 1. Общее физическое размещение для всех поддоменов.
 2. Предоставляем возможность компании переехать на отдельный физический носитель за дополнительную плату.
 3. Если компания разрастается настолько, что ее база данных занимает объем физического пространства больше x. Принудительно переводим ее на отдельный физический носитель.

Таким образом, оптимальное решение - решить обе задачи:

1. Все поддомены ссылаются на один физический адрес.
2. Любой поддомен может "переехать" на отдельный физический адрес.

Что касается обновления всех сайтов, то есть уже готовые решения, которые позволяют автоматически пересобрать (обновить) любое количество сайтов по одной команде. Например, можно использовать [Git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git) для этих целей.

Есть и другие, но ими я не пользовался, поэтому рекомендовать не могу.